# Angular5 - Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

Tags: npm, angular-5, angular-cli

Este erro acontece quando eu vou iniciar a aplicação:

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. Error: Local
>   workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
>       at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:37:19)
>       at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:24:21)
>       at ServeCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:195:32)
>       at ServeCommand. (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:47:25)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:7:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:3:12)
>       at ServeCommand.initialize (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:46:16)
>       at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:87:23)

Configurações:

Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 8.11.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 4.3.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     <error>
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   <error>
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.0
@angular/cli                      6.0.0
@schematics/angular               0.6.0
@schematics/update                0.6.0
rxjs                              5.4.2
typescript                        2.4.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atualize para a próxima versão do angular CLI

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@next
```

e recrie o projeto com `ng new project` , pois parece um erro em um dos releases https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases , há algumas informações aqui https://alligator.io/angular/angular-6/ sobre o comando ng update